# ERROR in ./~/node-env-file/lib/index.js Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs'

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

So, when attempting to require `node-env-file` in my config.js file as follows:

```
import Raven from 'raven-js';

const env = require('node-env-file');
env('.env');
```

I receive the following error mesage:

> ERROR in ./~/node-env-file/lib/index.js Module not found: Error:
>   Cannot resolve module 'fs' in
>   C:\Users\d0475\Documents\Projects\learn-redux-graphql\node_modules\node-env-file\lib
>   @ ./~/node-env-file/lib/index.js 3:9-22

My webpack config file is as follows:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './client/app'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
    // js
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client')
    },
    // CSS
    { 
      test: /\.styl$/, 
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'
    }
    ]
  }
};
```

and my package.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "learn-redux-graphql",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": ":) ",
  "scripts": {
    "build:webpack": "set NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build:webpack",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=production mocha './tests/**/*.spec.js' --compilers js:babel-core/register",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "start": "node devServer.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "Theo Mer",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-client": "^1.0.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-display-name": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "eslint": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^4.1.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "firebase": "^3.3.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^1.3.2",
    "graphql-tools": "^0.10.1",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "node-env-file": "^0.1.8",
    "raven-js": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^0.14.7",
    "react-apollo": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.2",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.2",
    "redbox-react": "^1.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.5.5-alpha.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.23.0",
    "expect": "^1.14.0",
    "expect-jsx": "^2.3.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "env": {
      "development": {
        "plugins": [
          [
            "transform-object-rest-spread"
          ],
          [
            "transform-react-display-name"
          ],
          [
            "react-transform",
            {
              "transforms": [
                {
                  "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
                  "imports": [
                    "react"
                  ],
                  "locals": [
                    "module"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "transform": "react-transform-catch-errors",
                  "imports": [
                    "react",
                    "redbox-react"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      "production": {
        "plugins": [
          [
            "transform-object-rest-spread"
          ],
          [
            "transform-react-display-name"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true
    },
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "node": true
    },
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "rules": {
      "quotes": [
        2,
        "single"
      ],
      "strict": [
        2,
        "never"
      ],
      "babel/generator-star-spacing": 1,
      "babel/new-cap": 1,
      "babel/object-shorthand": 1,
      "babel/arrow-parens": 1,
      "babel/no-await-in-loop": 1,
      "react/jsx-uses-react": 2,
      "react/jsx-uses-vars": 2,
      "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 2
    },
    "plugins": [
      "babel",
      "react"
    ]
  }
}
```

What is the here, and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [tell your webpack config about your node environment](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node). Add an entry for `node` into your webpack config with an empty value for the `fs` module:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    /* Your exisitng config as above */

    node: {
        fs: 'empty'
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm now getting the following error: ```Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
    at module.exports (bundle.js:75969)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:75870)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1864)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:587)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at bundle.js:579```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dotenv-webpack` has resolved the issue.